# Source of LDD models

Tags: ldd, advanced-models

I have just begun using LDD and want to teach my grandchild.  Is there a community inventory of some kind of LDD models that people share?

Answer (score 5):

Eurobricks has a very large list of official LEGO sets recreated in LDD by community members. I found it extremely useful. Look through the list and search for sets by set number and/or name: https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/41226-key-topic-official-lego-sets-made-in-ldd/

Comment: You're very welcome. :)

Comment: @BillDuncan then don't forget accepting the answre